# (Java) BufferedReader returning null when reading a file that isn't empty

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Each file has one line with one letter. Why are both are returning null?

```
File saveFile = new File("saved.txt");
File pocFile = new File("playerOrComputer.txt");

if (!pocFile.exists()) {
    pocFile.createNewFile();
}
if (!saveFile.exists()) {
    saveFile.createNewFile();
}   

BufferedReader brPoC = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pocFile));
BufferedReader brSave = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(saveFile));

String savedChar = brSave.readLine();
brSave.close();
String playerOrComputerChar = brPoC.readLine();
brPoC.close();

System.out.println(savedChar);
System.out.println(playerOrComputerChar);
```

Comment: you give both file names without path. Are you sure the current directory of your Java process if the directory the files are in?

Comment: I use eclipse, and I put them in the src and bin folders. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: If a file wasn't found, the `FileReader` constructor would be throwing `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: There is any exception for that. Because you need to put in out of src folder under Java Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the while loop while reading using BufferedReader:

```
while ((savedChar = brSave.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(savedChar);
            }
```

If your files Contains text it will definitely show:

Do not also leave the BufferedReader Open. Once you are done reading Close it:

```
if (brSave != null)br.close();
```

Comment: I did this, and also gave the absolute path. And its working now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the below lines.

```
if (!pocFile.exists()) {
    pocFile.createNewFile();
}
if (!saveFile.exists()) {
    saveFile.createNewFile();
}
```

you have checked if not exists you are creating new file. I think it creates a new file.

Comment: I commented them out, and it still returns null.

Comment: There is any exception for that. Because you need to put in out of src folder under Java Project

Answer (score 0):

try giving the `absolute path` in the `File` constructor and in the `absolute` path replace `\` by `\\` in order to get rid of the escape sequence

Comment: I tried but it gave me this error:

Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: You have to escape backslashes in string literals. Replace \ with \\

Comment: please provide your path that you are mentioning

Comment: it is because of the escape sequence that you are facing this issue

Comment: try replacing \ with / or replace \ with \\ in your absolute path

Comment: do vote up if it worked and you can select only one answer as the best answer

Comment: Unfortunately i can't vote up because I don't have the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving complete location path of file `File saveFile = new File("C:\\testing.txt");`

And you can do this

```
if (!saveFile.exists()) {
System.out.println("File doesn't exits! Creating new file..");
saveFile.createNewFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either try with the absolute path or if you are considering these files as part of your application, I mean if put in source folder, then you may use:

```
BufferedReader brPoC = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("saved.txt"));
BufferedReader brSave = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("playerOrComputer.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why are both are returning null?

With respect to you,both files contain some data.The IDE not able to find the files from location.

try `getAbsolutePath()` will return the exact path of your file.

```
saveFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

> Its always better to null check while using readLine()